# Calculate two random numbers for preventing spamming of register members in PHP

Tags: php, random

I would like to design a simple webpage for registering of the members.

Everything I almost done but I want to set a question about anti-spamming, by using the calculation of random numbers.

The problem is the random numbers are changed while I clicked the button "submit" of POST method, so the answer will incorrect forever, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
$rand1 = rand(0, 99);
$rand2 = rand(0, 99);

echo "<html> 
        <head><title>Member Registation</title></head>
            <body>
                <form action='memberReg.php' method='POST'>
                    <br />Please enter your name:<br/>
                    Username: <input type='text' name='username' class='form'/><br/>
                    <br />Please enter your password <br/>(At least 8 characters, maximum 20 characters):<br/>
                    Password: <input type='password' name='password' class='form'/><br /><br/>
                    Confirm password: <br/><input type='password' name='confirmPW' class='form'/><br/>
                    <br/>Please fill in the answer into textbox:<br/>
                    <br/>$rand1 + $rand2 = <input type='text' name='answer' class='form'/><br/>
                    <br/><input type='submit' value='Register' class='button'/><br/>
                    <br/><a href = memberLogin.php>Go Back</a>
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>";

if(isset($_POST["answer"])&&isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"])&&isset($_POST["confirmPW"])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
    $passConfirm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["confirmPW"]);
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["answer"]);

    if($username == "" || $password == "" || $passConfirm == ""|| $answer == ""){
        echo "Username/Password/Confirm password/Answer cannot be null.";
        return;
    }elseif($answer != ($rand1+$rand2)){
        echo "The answer is incorrect, please edit.";
        return;
    }elseif($username==$password||$username==$passConfirm){
        echo "Password/Confirm password cannot be the same with username, please check.";
        return;
    }elseif($password!=$passConfirm){
        echo "Confirm Password is not be same with password, please check.";
        return;
    }elseif((strlen($password) < 8||strlen($password) > 20)){
        echo "Password's length did not meet the standard, please change it.";
        return;
    }elseif((strlen($passConfirm) < 8||strlen($passConfirm) > 20)){
        echo "Password's length did not meet the standard, please change it.";
        return;
    }else{
        if($regApplicant->register($username, $password)){
            echo "Register Successfully. You can go back and Login";
        }else{
            echo "The username is already exist. Please change it.<br>";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just check if you already generated the random numbers if yes don't make them new and if not make new ones (e.g. simple if else)

Comment: I have tried but the random numbers still change after posting the answer

Comment: @learn_PHP May be you can show us your updated code ;)

Comment: Add `$sum = $rand1 + $rand2`, then `<input type=hidden name=actual_sum value=$sum>`, and then in your code compare `$_POST['answer']` against `$_POST['actual_sum']`. Note that @Rizier123, @MyticMoon and @Extrakun are all wrong suggesting that random numbers will magically be passed to the second script execution -- they will not be, you need to pass them somehow, either via hidden fields, or by storing them in some persistent storage, such as database or disk, alongside with some unique session identifier.

Comment: @Ishamael Oic, you're right. It should set an answer with type='hidden' for comparing with the $_POST["answer"]. Thanks for all.

Comment: @learn_PHP, feel free to accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working script for you. See my comment to your question with some details.

```php
$rand1 = rand(0, 99);
$rand2 = rand(0, 99);
$sum = $rand1 + $rand2;

echo "<html> 
        <head><title>Member Registation</title></head>
            <body>
                <form action='memberReg.php' method='POST'>
                    <br />Please enter your name:<br/>
                    Username: <input type='text' name='username' class='form'/><br/>
                    <br />Please enter your password <br/>(At least 8 characters, maximum 20 characters):<br/>
                    Password: <input type='password' name='password' class='form'/><br /><br/>
                    Confirm password: <br/><input type='password' name='confirmPW' class='form'/><br/>
                    <input type='hidden' name='actualSum' value='$sum'/>
                    <br/>Please fill in the answer into textbox:<br/>
                    <br/>$rand1 + $rand2 = <input type='text' name='answer' class='form'/><br/>
                    <br/><input type='submit' value='Register' class='button'/><br/>
                    <br/><a href = memberLogin.php>Go Back</a>
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>";

if(isset($_POST["answer"])&&isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"])&&isset($_POST["confirmPW"])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
    $passConfirm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["confirmPW"]);
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["answer"]);

    if($username == "" || $password == "" || $passConfirm == ""|| $answer == ""){
        echo "Username/Password/Confirm password/Answer cannot be null.";
        return;
    }elseif($answer != $_POST['actualSum']){
        echo "The answer is incorrect, please edit.";
        return;
    }elseif($username==$password||$username==$passConfirm){
        echo "Password/Confirm password cannot be the same with username, please check.";
        return;
    }elseif($password!=$passConfirm){
        echo "Confirm Password is not be same with password, please check.";
        return;
    }elseif((strlen($password) < 8||strlen($password) > 20)){
        echo "Password's length did not meet the standard, please change it.";
        return;
    }elseif((strlen($passConfirm) < 8||strlen($passConfirm) > 20)){
        echo "Password's length did not meet the standard, please change it.";
        return;
    }else{
        if($regApplicant->register($username, $password)){
            echo "Register Successfully. You can go back and Login";
        }else{
            echo "The username is already exist. Please change it.<br>";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It is not a very good protection against automatic submission, because now the spammer can just fake the sum in the hidden field, but on the other hand, nothing stops him from parsing the page and extracting the numbers anyway. If you actually need a good way to stop spammers, use recapcha or some other existing capcha service instead..

Answer (score 0):

You should only generate the random numbers when post-variables are not set. So you can do this in your else-part, at the end of your code. Otherwise you could pass the random numbers in a hidden form-field. Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Process your form before rendering the form - this way you will only generate the random numbers and form if the user has not submitted anything.

Also, look into using [redirects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) once the user has successfully registered, so that he won't be shown the form again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple check if the random number already exists will just work.
Alternative: you can consider Google Recapcha. Fun to play with.
[Google Recapcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)